Product of Asymptotic Expansions
Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be two smooth functions with the following asymptotic expansions:
$$
f(x)\backsim\sum_{k=-\infty}^{q_f-1}a_kx^k,\ |x|\rightarrow\infty,
$$
$$
g(x)\backsim\sum_{k=-\infty}^{q_g-1}b_kx^k,\ |x|\rightarrow\infty,
$$
with $q_f,q_g\in \mathbb{N}$ some integers and $a_k, b_k \in \mathbb{C}$. I.e. for every $K\in \mathbb{N}$ there is $C_K>0$ such that for all $x$ large enough
$$
\left| f(x)-\sum^{q_f-1}_{n=-K}a_kx^k \right| \leq C_Kx^{-(K+1)}.
$$
I want to prove that the product $fg$ also has an asymptotic expansion of the same form, i.e.
$$
f(x)g(x)\backsim\sum_{k=-\infty}^{q_{fg}-1}c_kx^k,\ |x|\rightarrow\infty
$$
I tried adjusting the proof from this notes on p. 19 to my case, but without success.
My proof attempt:
Proof. Write $N_{f}=q_{f}-1$ and same $N_{g}$. Then rewrite
\begin{aligned}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{N_{f}}a_{k}x^{k} & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{N_{f}-k}x^{N_{f}-k}\\
 & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\tilde{a}_{k}x^{N_{f}-k}.
\end{aligned}
Then using Cauchy product
\begin{aligned}\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{N_{f}}\tilde{a}_{k}x^{k}\right)\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{N_{g}}\tilde{b}_{k}x^{k}\right) & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{k}x^{N_{fg}-2k+m}\\
 & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{k}\tilde{a}_{m}\tilde{b}_{k-m}x^{N_{fg}-2k+m},
\end{aligned}
with $N_{fg}=N_{f}+N_{g}$. Let $K\in\mathbb{N}$, then
\begin{aligned}fg-\sum_{k=0}^{K}c_{k}x^{N_{fg}-k} & =fg-\sum_{k=0}^{K}\sum_{m=0}^{k}\tilde{a}_{m}\tilde{b}_{k-m}x^{N_{fg}-2k+m}\\
 & =fg-\sum_{m=0}^{K}\tilde{a}_{m}x^{N_{f}-m}\sum_{k=0}^{K-m}\tilde{b}_{k}x^{N_{g}-2k}\\
 & =fg-\sum_{m=0}^{K}\tilde{a}_{m}x^{N_{f}-m}\sum_{k=0}^{K-m}\tilde{b}_{k}x^{N_{g}-2k}\\
 & +g\sum_{m=0}^{K}\tilde{a}_{m}x^{N_{f}-m}-g\sum_{m=0}^{K}\tilde{a}_{m}x^{N_{f}-m}\\
 & =g\left[f-\sum_{m=0}^{K}\tilde{a}_{m}x^{N_{f}-m}\right]+\sum_{m=0}^{K}\tilde{a}_{m}x^{N_{f}-m}\left[g-\sum_{k=0}^{K-m}\tilde{b}_{k}x^{N_{g}-2k}\right]
\end{aligned}
Thus for large enough $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{aligned}\left|fg-\sum_{k=0}^{K}c_{k}x^{N_{fg}-k}\right| & =\left|g\left[f-\sum_{m=0}^{K}\tilde{a}_{m}x^{N_{f}-m}\right]+\sum_{m=0}^{K}\tilde{a}_{m}x^{N_{f}-m}\left[g-\sum_{k=0}^{K-m}\tilde{b}_{k}x^{N_{g}-2k}\right]\right|\\
 & \leq\left|g(x)\right|C_{K}^{f}x^{-(K+1)}+\left|\sum_{m=0}^{K}\tilde{a}_{m}x^{N_{f}-m}\left[g-\sum_{k=0}^{K-m}\tilde{b}_{k}x^{N_{g}-2k}\right]\right|
\end{aligned}
I don't know how I can bound the last inequality by $C_Kx^{-(K+1)}$ for some $C_K >0$ so I guess something I did is wrong.
It would be awesome if you know how to proceed or a different way to prove it.
Thank you

The claim is true. Write your functions exactly as their truncated asymptotic expansions plus remainder terms. Then express the remainder of the truncated asymptotic expansion of the product in terms of the remainders at various truncations and the coefficients of the two original expansions.

In addition to @Gary 's advice, read about the Cauchy product of power series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

@Gary, I added my attempt at proof. If I understand correctly, your advice is something like what I did(?). The remainder of the product is expressed as the reminder of $f$ and $g$, but I cannot bound some of its terms. Not sure how to proceed.


I guess something I did is wrong.

I did not read your proof attempt because it is too cumbersome.
I think that doing technical, routine proofs or calculations, although we are proceeding straightforwardly, we should care about the proof convenience, simplicity, its technical details. So we have to look for the ways to simplify the proof, to make it more convenient, in particular, by choosing convenient variables and notation. Moreover, I think this care also makes proofs or calculations less erroneous.
So, let us begin.
I assume that $0\not\in\mathbb N$. For the sake of simplicity put $p_f=q_f-1$ and $p_q=q_g-1$. Note that both $p_f$ and $p_q$ are nonnegative. Now put  $p_{fg}=p_f+p_g$, and for each integer $k\le p_{fq}$ put $c_k=\sum  a_i+b_j$, where the sum is over (finitely many) all pairs $(i,j)$ of integers $i\le p_f$ and $j\le p_g$ such that $i+j=k$.
Given any $K\in\mathbb N$ pick $C>0$ and $R\ge 1$ such that for all $x>R$ we have $|r_f(x)|\le Cx^{-(K+1+p_g)}$ and $|r_g(x)|\le Cx^{-(K+1+p_f)}$, where
$$
r_f(x)=f(x)-\sum^{p_f}_{k=-K-p_g}a_kx^k\mbox{ and }r_g(x)=g(x)-\sum^{p_g}_{k=-K-p_f}b_kx^k.
$$
Moreover, pick $D>0$ such that for all $x>R$ we have
$$\left|\sum^{p_f}_{k=-K-p_g}a_kx^k\right|\le Dx^{p_f}\mbox{ and }  
\left|\sum^{p_g}_{k=-K-p_f}b_kx^k\right|\le Dx^{p_g}.$$
Then
$$f(x)g(x)=\left(r_f(x)+\sum^{p_f}_{k=-K-p_g}a_kx^k\right)
\left(r_g(x)+\sum^{p_g}_{k=-K-p_f}b_kx^k\right)=$$ $$r_f(x)r_g(x)+\sum^{p_{fg}}_{k=-K} c_kx^k+h(x^{-1})x^{-(K+1)}+
r_f(x)\sum^{p_g}_{k=-K-p_f}b_kx^k+r_g(x)\sum^{p_f}_{k=-K-p_g}a_kx^k,$$
where $h$ is a polynomial.
So there exists $E>0$ such that $h(x^{-1})\le E$ for all $x>R$.
Therefore if $x>R$ then $$\left|f(x)g(x)-\sum^{p_{fg}}_{k=-K} c_kx^k\right|\le C^2x^{-(2K+2+p_f+p_g)}+(E+2CD)x^{-(K+1)},$$
so it suffices to put $C_K=C^2+E+2CD$.

Thank you very much for most informative answer. This helped me a lot. Regarding the polynomial $h$ - Did you note it for readability and clarity or does it have an additional meaning?
